# Node: dealing with async nature

Tags: node.js

This is throwing me for a bit of a loop; I'm not entirely sure how to phase the question. I have an object with several properties which are fetched from, and written to, a database. An example might be:

```
// This is an over simplified example. this._connection() returns a valid DB connection
var delay = {
  'time' : function() {
    this._connection().query('SELECT * FROM delay', function(err, result, fields) {
      return result.length ? result[0].time : 60;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if I try to use this code ....

```
console.log('Current Delay:' + delay.time());
```

It prints, as I should have expected, 'undefined' because the mySQL callback didn't execute before the method `delay()` returned, and so the `return` inside the callback doesn't do anything.

Is there an accepted method for dealing with this sort of thing? Maybe I'm just unable to wrap my head around node.js/async.

Comment: I think putting the console.log inside of the callback function would be the way to make it work

Comment: @Daniel Elliott: I think you've taken the example a bit too literally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called callbacks

```
var delay = {
  'time' : function(data, cb) {
    this._connection().query('SELECT * FROM delay', function(err, result, fields) {
      if (err) {
        // return early to avoid else
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, result.length ? result[0].time : 60);
    }
  }
}

delay.time(null, function (err, time) {
  console.log('Current Delay:' + time);
});
```

Note that `return` statements in inner functions are useless. `return` does not magically propogate to call `return` on the outer function. That's because functions have an implecit `return undefined;` at the end of them